# How to add a score and display it on the screen

Tags: java, user-interface, button, actionlistener

I'm basically making a [bass guitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_guitar) playing application where you click buttons to play the notes. I want to add a score counter for when the right sequence of buttons are clicked (to play a song), so I made a JButton array of the notes to play in order. My problem is making the score and displaying it on the screen.

This is my array:

```
private static JButton buttons[] = {string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7, string8};
```

This is my score counter method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    jb = (JButton)e.getSource();
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        if (jb == (buttons[i])) {
            totalOccurrences += 1;
            score.setText("score: " + totalOccurrences + "/8");
        }
        else
        {
            totalOccurrences -= 1;
            score.setText("score: " + totalOccurrences + "/8");
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a *text area* to the UI, and ensure that the data output goes there and not to the console. Set an actionListener, which will tell the button what to do.

See *[How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)*.